# Adding a Control inside a TextBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, textbox

i am trying to make a usercontrol that will emulate a regular textbox, but has tags. Something along the lines of this:

[image]

but i am having trouble...I tried to do this:

```
<TextBox> 
    <Border/>
</TextBox>
```

but that will not work. How would i do this, without using a richTextBox?

Thanks

Comment: I believe you need to create a custom style for the TextBox. Unfortunately it is not trivial.

Comment: how would i make a custom style like that?

Comment: Try this to help you get started http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/139563/Custom-WPF-TextBox-Style. It isn't exactly what you need but hopefully points you in the right direction

Comment: Another example http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/487972/How-to-extend-a-WPF-Textbox-to-Custom-Picker

Comment: i am not completely sure that the styling will effect the controls ability to contain custom controls

Comment: oh, you meant template styling...ok, let me try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TextBox is not a container, and therefore hasn't children. Perhaps try wrapping the TextBox in a container object?

Some example code to get you started:

```
    <Border Grid.Row="0" BorderBrush="#FF808080" Background="#FFFFFFFF" >
        <DockPanel>
            <ItemsControl DockPanel.Dock="Left" ItemsSource="{Binding Tags}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <WrapPanel />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Border BorderBrush="#FF000000" BorderThickness="1" Margin="3">
                            <DockPanel>
                                <Button DockPanel.Dock="Right" Content="X" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Margin="3" />
                            </DockPanel>
                        </Border>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
            <TextBox BorderThickness="0" Text="{Binding Text}" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" />
        </DockPanel>
    </Border>
```

Restyle and rebind however best fits into your solution.